# DAX Calculate Average when all categories are present

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with three columns

```
[date],
[category_1],
[category_2],
[value]
```

I would like to plot a line chart with `[date]` in the X axis, `[value]` in the Y-axis and `[category_1]` on the legend. 
I would like the `[value]` to be averaged over the `[category_2]` but to be presented only for the `[date]` and `[category_1]` values for which ALL `[category_2]` members are present. If for a given combination of `[date]` and `[category_1]` not all types of `[category_2]` are present then I wouldn't like the average to be presented in the visual.

I understand I should probably use a measure in which the Average is calculated applying a filter in which the number of `[category_2]` members is equal to the total but so far I haven't found the correct DAX expression. Happy to consider other approaches if possible without creating a DAX measure.

As example, with the following input table:

[image]

The resulting measure would be:

[image]

There is no result for the last 3 rows because they don't represent both `[category_2]` values

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if you had some sample input data and desired output. An [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) goes a long ways to getting an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, adding example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to have your measure throw a blank if not all values of `Category_2` are present.

```
myMeasure = IF(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Category_2]) =
                   CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Category_2]), ALL(Table1)),
               AVERAGE(Table1[Value]),
               BLANK())
```

This gives the average if the distinct count of the `Category_2` values in the local filter context matches the distinct count of `Category_2` over the entire table, otherwise, it gives a blank.

[image: Table Visual]